# Just need some help figuring out and understanding the answers to my test questions

Tags: java, iterator, comparable

I did not do so well on my last exam in my class specifically on the multiple choice. Was just wondering if yall can help me find out where I went wrong for a couple of the questions. There can be more than one answer to these questions btw as an example the correct answer could be a, b, d etc...

```
package a;

public class B <T extends Comparable <T>> implements C<T>
```

**Question 1**: Consider the class above, which of the following description is/are correct?

A: A is an interface.

B: B is an interface.

C: Comparable is an interface.

D: C is an interface.

E: T is an interface.

For this question, I answered D which i think is correct. So Im assuming theres another correct answer that I didn't circle as well on my test.

**Questions 2**:

Consider the class B above(same bit of code from previous question), which of the following relation is/are correct?

A:B is A

b: B is C

C: B is Comparable

D: T is Comparable

E: B has Comparable

I answered C, however now I'm thinking the correct answer could have been both b, and d?

**Question 4**:
Consider Java's Iterator and Comparable. Which of the following descriptions is/are correct?

A: both are generic classes.

b: both are generic interfaces.

c: Iterator can improve the efficiency of applications using Array List.

D: Iterator can improve the efficiency of applications using linked List.

For this I answered a, and d. I really have no idea about this one.

if you guys give me answers, please try to explain them as I want to actually learn the correct answers and why. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Assuming that `Comparable` refers to `java.lang.Comparable`, [it is also an interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Comment: @AndyTurner ahhhh ok, would that make T an interface as well since it is extending Comparable?

Comment: No. `T` is just a type variable, and could refer to either a class or an interface.